# Kivy: how to make a RecycleGridLayout with 2 cols:

Tags: python, list, listview, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to Python and Kivy, and I need to display a RecycleGridLayout with 2 cols where the first column gives me the position of the second column, for now it shows the list that I created in a single column

here's my .py file

```
class Introduccion(Screen):
    numbers = ObjectProperty()
    number_list = ObjectProperty([])
    def Add_ToList(self):
        self.number_list.data.append({'text': str(self.numbers.text)})
```

and my .kv file

```
BoxLayout:
    pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.3, 'center_x':0.4}
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 250
    pos: 200, 100
    RecycleView:
        id: number_list_view
        viewclass: 'Label'
        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            default_size: None, dp(26)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

**my other question is how do I add a button to clear the list, i tried with a button with the function `self.number_list.data.clear()`  but only delete it with a row, if you have more than one, an error appears**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your former arrangement with `RecycleBoxLayout` to display a single column that looks like two columns. For example, a custom `viewclass`:

```
class MyViewClass(BoxLayout):
    position = StringProperty('')
    text = StringProperty('')
```

with a `kv` rule like:

```
<MyViewClass>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    Label:
        text: root.position
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
    Label:
        text: root.text
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
```

will display two adjacent `Labels` (like two columns).

Then, in your `RecycleBoxLayout`, set the `viewclass` as:

```
    RecycleView:
        id: number_list_view
        viewclass: 'MyViewClass'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
        .
        .
        .
```

Then, when you add `data` to the `RecycleView`, each dictionary in the `data` list would have two entries. For example:

```
self.number_list.data.append({'position': 'this is position', 'text': text})
```

As for clearing the entire `RecycleView`, you can just reset the entire `data` list, something like this:

```
        on_press: root.number_list.data = []
```